# PostgresSQL ORDER BY clause with CASE for sorted column

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a simple form of `SELECT ORDER BY` query which is using `CASE` for creating sorted id's. 
I referred two approaches based on https://gist.github.com/cpjolicoeur/3590737 and used one of them.

```
SELECT id FROM tasks t ORDER BY 
CASE 
WHEN t.type = 'TypeA' THEN 1 
WHEN t.type = 'TypeB' THEN 2 
WHEN t.type = 'TypeC' THEN 3 
END, 
CASE 
WHEN t.state = 'Interrupted' THEN 4 
WHEN t.state = 'Terminated' THEN 5 
WHEN t.state = 'Completed' THEN 6
WHEN t.state = 'Killed' THEN 7
WHEN t.state = 'Warning' THEN 8
WHEN t.state = 'Starting' THEN 9
WHEN t.state = 'New' THEN 10
WHEN t.state = 'Running' THEN 11
END, 
modified ASC;
```

The above query is based on below criteria to sort ids:

1. TypeA with state:
   Interrupted,Terminated,Completed,Killed,Warning,Starting,New,Running
2. TypeB with state:
   Interrupted,Terminated,Completed,Killed,Warning,Starting,New,Running
3. TypeC with state:
   Interrupted,Terminated,Completed,Killed,Warning,Starting,New,Running

I need to modify this sql for below sorting criteria now:

1. TypeA with state: Interrupted,Terminated,Completed,Killed
2. TypeB with state: Interrupted,Terminated,Completed,Killed
3. TypeC with state: Interrupted,Terminated
4. TypeA with state: Warning,Starting,New,Running
5. TypeB with state: Warning,Starting,New,Running
6. TypeC with state: Completed,Killed,Warning,Starting,New,Running

Please note the ordering of 'state'(as specified) is equally important here for a 'type'

I am trying to modify above sql so that it meets the new criteria. Being not an sql expert I am looking for most efficient way to rewrite this sql which could also accommodate slight changes on sorting criteria in near future.

To further clarify sharing example below:

sample data

```
id  | type  |    state
----+-------+-------------
 1  | TypeC | Completed
 2  | TypeA | Completed
 3  | TypeA | Running
 4  | TypeB | Completed
 5  | TypeB | Running
 6  | TypeC | Terminated
 7  | TypeC | Unknown
 8  | TypeA | Completed
 9  | TypeB | Interrupted
 10 | TypeB | Completed
 11 | TypeB | Interrupted
 12 | TypeC | Killed
 13 | TypeC | Running
 14 | TypeB | Warning
 15 | TypeB | Running
 16 | TypeB | Killed
```

expected data

```
id  | type  |    state
--- +-------+-------------
 1  | TypeA | Completed
 8  | TypeA | Completed
 9  | TypeB | Interrupted
 11 | TypeB | Interrupted
 4  | TypeB | Completed
 10 | TypeB | Completed
 16 | TypeB | Killed
 7  | TypeC | Unknown
 6  | TypeC | Terminated
 3  | TypeA | Running
 14 | TypeB | Warning
 5  | TypeB | Running
 15 | TypeB | Running
 1  | TypeC | Completed
 12 | TypeC | Killed
 13 | TypeC | Running
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe something like this?

```
CASE 
WHEN t.type = 'TypeA' AND t.state 
        IN ( 'Interrupted','Terminated','Completed','Killed') 
  THEN 1
WHEN t.type = 'TypeB' AND t.state 
        IN ( 'Interrupted','Terminated','Completed','Killed') 
  THEN 2
..
..
```

**EDIT**

I would recommend you to create a hierarchy table, this way your query gets simpler.

```
CREATE TABLE type_state_hier AS
select *  FROM 
(
 VALUES
(1,'TypeA','Interrupted'),
(2,'TypeA','Terminated'),
(3,'TypeA','Completed'),
(4,'TypeA','Killed'),
(5,'TypeB','Interrupted'),
(6,'TypeB','Terminated'),
(7,'TypeB','Completed'),
(8,'TypeB','Killed'),
(9,'TypeC','Interrupted'),
(10,'TypeC','Terminated'),
(11,'TypeA','Warning'),
(12,'TypeA','Starting'),
(13,'TypeA','New'),
(14,'TypeA','Running'),
(15,'TypeB','Warning'),
(16,'TypeB','Starting'),
(17,'TypeB','New'),
(18,'TypeB','Running'),
(19,'TypeC','Completed'),
(20,'TypeC','Killed'),
(21,'TypeC','Warning'),
(22,'TypeC','Starting'),
(23,'TypeC','New'),
(24,'TypeC','Running')
) As s(rnk,type,state)
;
```

Now, query it with a simple join with your main table.

```
select t.* from tasks t 
  join type_state_hier h on 
  h.type=t.type and h.state = t.state
order by h.rnk ,t.id
```

If you don't want to create a table, simply use it as a CTE (refer demo)

[**DEMO**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=266fea5aad1861c763299fc848c887f8)

Comment: Does it ensure the desired state ordering is achieved?

Comment: @akhi : how will I know? You mentioned it, without providing  any sample data/ expected output to describe your question.

Comment: okay, so IN ensures the match is done based on the ordering that we specify i.e in braces (1,2 ,3,4...)

Comment: @akhi : it doesn't. as I said, you didn't make it clear in your question.

Comment: sorry if it was not clear, have added a note and edited the question. Actually the original query ensures the ordering of state as well.

Comment: Hi Kaushik, your solution will not give desired results. can you suggest any solution?

Comment: @akhi : Without sample data and expected result, it is not possible to provide any working solution. All, we could do is to guess if a solution might work for you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190684/discussion-between-akhi-and-kaushik-nayak).

Comment: Added sample data and expected result

Comment: Thanks Kaushik, I liked your idea of creating a hierarchy table. It makes the solution really simple.